# is there any way to format a string as input so that C interprets it as hex?

Tags: c

I know that you can tell C to interpret a value as hex using printf("\xab"). If you input "\xab" to a C program as input it will interpret it as the characters -x-a-b. Is there any way to embed printf-style formatting information into raw input?

Comment: not sure what you mean but if you mean what i think you mean then that would be a mean security hole.

Comment: Do you just mean e.g. to allow a user to input 0xff and store that as 255? Or in processing command line arguments?

Comment: If the input is from a terminal then it's between you and your terminal program (and the shell, for command line arguments), whether it provides a means for you to "type in" non-display characters. The C program just sees a series of bytes, each of which has a value. It doesn't know what keypresses provoked those values, and it doesn't care that byte values might be represented in hex. If the input is from a file, you can use a hex editor to create a file containing any byte values you choose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it all depends on how the code that reads the characters interpret them. You can't magically force a program to do something else from the outside, by giving it text. I guess a buffer overrun attack is a bit of a counter-example, but that's rather extreme.

Many programs that use e.g. [`strtol()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strtol) automatically support `0x` (hex) and `0` as prefixes (browser address bars being one common example of this rather unexpected feature). For instance, in Windows you can do this to ping this site:

```
C:\>ping 0xc6fcce10

Pinging 198.252.206.16 with 32 bytes of data:
```

Where 0xc6fcce10 is the IP address as a single 32-bit hexadecimal number.